# I have This error (Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. ) in context How can I resoled it?

Tags: flutter, dart

[I have an error in context How can I resoled it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZMRN.png)

I have an error in context How can I resoled it?
What is the correct way to solve this problem?
Don't say call the Dart.js library
Because it creates another problem

```
import '../../generated/l10n.dart';

class ValidatorDef {
  static String? validatorEmail(val) {
    if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
      return S.of(context).validator_Email;
    }
    if (!val.contains("@") || !val.contains(".")) {
      return "الرجاء ادخال بريد الكتروني صحيح";
    }
    return null;
  }

  static String? validatorPassword(val) {
    if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
      return "الرجاء ادخال كلمة المرور";
    }
    return null;
  }

  static String? validatorname(val) {
    if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
      return "الرجاء ادخال الاسم";
    }
    return null;
  }

  static String? validatorPhone(val) {
    if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
      return "الرجاء ادخال رقم الهاتف";
    }
    if ((val.toString()).length < 11) {
      return "رقم الهاتف غير صحيح";
    }
  
    return null;
  }

  static String? validatorRegion(val) {
    if (val == null || val.isEmpty) {
      return "الرجاء اختيار منطقة ";
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the "S" class?  How is this class being used?  Was this code generated by an LLM, or written by hand?

Comment: This code is for localization

Comment: locale: const Locale('ar'),
          localizationsDelegates: const [
                S.delegate,
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,

Comment: `return S.of(context).validator_Email`  What is "context" supposed to be?  I do not see a definition or declaration of that variable anywhere in this code.

Comment: this for localization :
locale: const Locale('ar'), localizationsDelegates: const [ S.delegate, GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate, GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, ], supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,

Comment: Localizations always need a context, because parts of your app can be in different localization contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a context from wherever you're calling `ValidatorDef.validatorEmail(...)`. First, add the parameter:

```dart
class ValidatorDef {
  static String? validatorEmail(BuildContext context, String? val) {
```

Now when you call the method, pass the context from widget:

```dart
ValidatorDef.validatorEmail(context, 'An example string');
```

---

If this method is called from a scope where there's no context there, repeat this pattern for the caller of this method.